# How to prefix € sign and suffix % sign for 2 column in python dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe

[image]

and I want to add € sign and % sign to my resultant dataframe where there are values and not to all rows. My final dataframe would be

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
df = lit(col('€'+'Currency'))
df= lit(col('Average'+'%'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what happened when you tried that?

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve given input columns

Comment: try casting it to string first then concat

Comment: what happens when you try `"\N{euro sign}"` and `"\N{percent sign}"`

Comment: @drum the columns are string type. Its still not working

Comment: @tldr I tried it. But no luck

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7803343/tldr I am curious to know how your suggestion of "\N{euro sign}" works out. Can you point me to few links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pyspark it should be of simple **when() otherwise()** implementation. **Make sure to cast the column Data Type to SrtingType()** instead of DoubleType().

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Sample Dataframe
data = [(None,"55.6"),("492.38",None)]
columns=["Currency","Average"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)

# Implementation
df = df.withColumn("Currency", F.when(df.Currency.isNotNull(), F.concat(F.lit("$"),df.Currency)).otherwise(df.Currency))\
  .withColumn("Average", F.when(df.Average.isNotNull(), F.concat(df.Average, F.lit("%"))).otherwise(df.Average))
df.show()

#+--------+-------+
#|Currency|Average|
#+--------+-------+
#|    null|  55.6%|
#| $492.38|   null|
#+--------+-------+
```